tex compiler yield spurious timezone
I am in Timezone GMT+02, Germany.
SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=0 FORCE_SOURCE_DATE=1 lualatex test

means that lualatex runs with time 0 seconds since 1970-01-01 midnight.
To be more precise, it is the time when in GMT it was 1970-01-01 midnight.
Checking metadata by
pdfinfo -isodates test.pdf

yields
CreationDate:    1970-01-01T01:00:00+01

Note that it is one hour later in a timezone GMT+01.
This is equivalent with 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, where Z refers to GMT.
So the time is ok.
But still i am in GMT+02. So I would have expected 1970-01-01T02:00:00+02.
Seemingly, the timezone is not respected although the point in time is correct.
Now comes something a bit confusing to me: the variable for timezone TZ has another sign as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637603/understanding-tztime-zone-variable-in-unix
Ok so my timezone is TZ=GMT-02.
If i make this explicit, i.e.
SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=0 FORCE_SOURCE_DATE=1 TZ=GMT-02 lualatex test

the result is as expected: 1970-01-01T02:00:00+02.
By the way, pdflatex behaves different: result is 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
xelatex yields the same, but in contrast to the other two has only creation time
but does not set modification time.
Strange enough, the timezone is ok if the SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH is not given at all.
More generally, if the time given is not midnight, the problem seems also not to occur.
It is conceivable that I am mislead by misconception
but at the moment looks like a bug to me.
`

Which OS? What does pdfinfo -rawdates return?

if you compile with lualatex --utc test the time will use the Z: D:19700101000000Z. Apart from this I refuse to think what winter/summertime means here.

@cfr I have linux, but this is immaterial. pdfinfo is offered by texlive and by miktex.
From pdfinfo -- help you find out: displays the date/time info in raw format, as offered by PDF specification 2.0 section 7.9.4. You can drop this, then you have US or sth. or you use -isodates instead which yields iso 8601 format.

@UlrikeFischer yes I refuse also. I hate this nonsense also. ... Well.. On one hand, you are right, I can use --utc so all problems gone.
But still, ... did I find a bug?? If so, well they wont fix too fast.
So in the meantime, your hint offers a workaround.
I had a look: lualatex is the only compiler which offers --utc. So, very specific solution. I could also run always with TZ=GMT.
This is a real workaround for all compiler. So you inspired a general solution.

@UlrikeFischer I made some experiments now.
I found: only lualatex offer timestamps other than UTC! This means that pdflatex and xelatex both write UTC only. Thus they don't have the option --utc.
Ok, but this means that the bug I am pointing on is specific for lualatex.
The simplest workaround is really the one you suggested: option --utc.

I know pdfinfo is cross-platform. Nothing guarantees the same results everywhere. In particular, there are differences in how typical Windows systems set the hardware clock which sometimes have repercussions at the OS level. I asked about -rawdates because it would tell you something about where the discrepancy comes in. Whether it picks up your TZ correctly would depend on your locale configuration, for instance.
